# Send value back from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++

I guess my problem is fairly straight-forward, however I can't find a way to solve it. My process is the following:

1. I run a Python script: Test.py.
2. Within that script, I am calling a c++ program.

Test.py:

```
RunCprogram = "./Example"
os.system(RunCprogram)
```

I want that `./Example` executable to return a double that can be used later in my Python script. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can make `Example` print the data to `stdout` then capture it with `subprocess` Python module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example based on @ForceBru answer:

`example.cpp`, compile with `g++ example.cpp -o example`

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << 3.14159 ;
    return 0;
}
```

`example.py`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import subprocess

res = subprocess.check_output(["./example"], universal_newlines=True)

print "The value of 2*" + u"\u03C0" + " is approximately " + str(2*float(res))
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, *make sure `Example` outputs the desired data to `stdout`*. If it's not, you can do nothing about it.

Then use the Python's `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess

res=subprocess.check_output(["./Example"], universal_newlines=True)
```

If `res` contains a newline at the end, remove it with `res.strip()`. Finally, cast `res` to `float` with `float(res)`.